# Emotion vs Feeling

Tags: difference, vocabulary

According to Oxford dictionary, feeling is something you feel through the mind or through the human senses.
While emotion is ​a strong feeling such as love, fear or anger; the part of a person’s character that consists of feelings.

It seems they are the same and they I understand it is, feelings might be phyiscal level or at a mental level.
But emotions are purely in the mind in terms of perception.

Is this understanding correct or is there finer subtleties to it?

Comment: The main senses of *emotion* all point to *feeling* as being synonymous. On the other hand, there are several sense of *feeling* that do not point back to *emotion* (although some do). In short (more or less) *emotion* is a kind of subset of *feeling*. However, the distinction made in the second paragraph here is not accurate.